# Installing phpMyAdmin without XAMPP or WAMP server (Windows)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL installed on my Windows system and I was wondering if there is a way to use it with phpMyAdmin without having to install a WAMP or XAMPP server on my computer as I do not want to install them. I have MySQL workbench installed but I want to use it on browser i.e with the phpMyAdmin user interface.

Comment: You can do it without WAMP or XAMPP but you'll have to install PHP and Apache/Nginx/Any web server capable of running PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for having MySQL and Phpmyadmin without LAMPP or WAMP is docker. you should get MySQL and PHPMyAdmin images and then create a container on port 3306 for MySQL and another custom port for PHPMyAdmin.
you can manage MySQL instances on PHPMyAdmin and create many different DB.
after installing docker in a folder create a mysql-compose.yaml for example and put the following codes:

```
version : '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: dev_mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: default_schema

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: dev_pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 8183:80
```

now run this command : docker-compose -f mysql-compose up -d

Answer (score 0):

After a brief search of the internet I found a website which I presume are helpful in installing phpMyAdmin without the use of `WAMP` or `XAMPP`. *The website is available* [here](http://www.badprog.com/windows-7-installing-php-apache-http-mysql-phpmyadmin-on-windows)!

It appears the website goes through a step-by-step tutorial on how to install firstly a web server onto your windows machine, then goes on to show you how to install extra's such as `phpMyAdmin`.

I do strongly suggest using software's such as `WAMP`; however, it's all up to you!

Comment: can you please post direct link if possible

Answer (score -1):

WAMP or XAMPP are software bundles with a preconfigured database (MySQL), a webserver (Apache) and some other tools (like phpMyAdmin and others)

In order to run phpMyAdmin:

1) you first need a webserver capable of running PHP pages,

2) then you need a configured and running MySQL database (which you already have)

3) then you need install and configure phpMyAdmin, on the webserver, it so it can access the MySQL database (providing DB username, password and communication ports)

4) then you need to run some SQL scripts on the MySQL server (or run some config preparations on phpMyAdmin)

As you can see, you will need several actions to make it run. You can follow up many step by step tutorials which tell you how to do that. That's why WAMPP and XAMP are preferred since it's install and use.

**Note**: You can install parts of WAMP or XAMPP, like skipping the install of MySQL, but you'll need to reconfigure the rest manually.